# Can C++ Compilers optimize overloaded default parameters?

Tags: c++, gcc, overloading

I've been refactoring a codebase for an embedded chip that uses a lot of convenient overloaded functions with default parameters, like this:

```cpp
int state, prevState;
float time;

void setState(int newState, float newtime)
{
    if (newState != state)
    {
        prevState = state;
        time = newTime;
    }
    state = newState;
}

inline void setState(int newState) 
{
    setState(newState, time);
}
```

In its current implementation, the second function is manually optimized:

```cpp
void setState(int newState) 
{
    if (newState != state)
        prevState = state;
    state = newState;
}
```

If I use the new implementation (the one with inline) is there a way for the compiler to recognize and remove the code involving time, or is the old manual way the best practice?

I've used Godbolt's compiler on GCC yet can't find an appropriate setting for code or a compile flag that doesn't obfuscate everything, or have the calls remain.

Comment: This depends on what your definition of "can" is. Yes, the C++ standard allows the compiler to perform any optimization that has no observable effects, like this one. So, the compiler can do it, according to the C++ standard. The other definition of "can" would be: will compilers typically do this optimization. For that, only empirical testing can determine that.

Comment: Have you benchmarked it? Stop worrying about such micro-optimizations until you do and proven it's a problem.

Comment: Firstly, have you done benchmarking to determine if such a transformation matters? If not, all you are doing is premature optimisation.  If you have done benchmarking, have you also observed the output from your compiler, with different optimisation settings, to find when it does (or does not) do the optimisation you describe? The C++ standard neither requires nor prevents such a transformation, so such optimisation behaviours are a QoI (quality of implementation) concern, not something you can assume or rely on.

Answer (score 1):

GCC generates exactly the same code for both variants with `-O3`: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nTGTEj4sP).

Note the the `inline` keyword is at best only considered as a suggestion in the compiler's decision regarding inlining. It's main effect is [something completely different](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline).

Comment: It always had the meaning "recommended for inlining" and the C++ standard still says as much. It may mean "multiple definitions are allowed" at the same time too. These aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: `inline` does have effect on codegen, being a hint that compilers sometimes take into account. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/75275572/2752075