# Why does making a function an inline function give a LNK2019 Error

Tags: c++, oop, inline

I have two files, Snake.h and Snake.cpp.

In Snake.h:

```
std::array<int, GAME_WIDTH* GAME_HEIGHT + 1> getSnake() const;
int getSize() const;
int getApple() const;
```

In Snake.cpp:

```
std::array<int, GAME_WIDTH* GAME_HEIGHT + 1> Snake::getSnake() const {
    return snake;
}

int Snake::getSize() const {
    return size;
}

int Snake::getApple() const {
    return apple;
}
```

When I try to make these inline functions, I get a LNK2019 error, but if I leave it as is it compiles and runs perfectly fine. Any ideas why this would be?

Exact error looks like this:
[image: Error screen]

Comment: 1. Please, [don't post your code/error messages as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4298200). Firstly we want to copy/paste it and secondly search engines are unable to index that information. So please make sure that any textual information is actually provided in text form. 2. It's unclear how/where you declare the member functions inline. It's always better when you post a not working code instead of describing how you change it for getting it not working.

Comment: So, the code you've posted works, and you've described how to change it to make it not work? Don't do that. Post the code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LNK2019 error usually indicates unresolved external symbols. When you make a function `inline`, the definition should be available at the point of instantiation. If the function definition is in a `.cpp` file, other translation units won't see the definition, causing the linker error.

Solutions:

1. Move the inline function definitions into the header file.
2. Use `inline` keyword in both declaration and definition, and include the header where needed.

Example for Solution 1:

```cpp
// In Snake.h
inline std::array<int, GAME_WIDTH* GAME_HEIGHT + 1> getSnake() const {
  return snake;
}
```

Now the inline function definition is in the header, making it visible to all translation units that include the header. This should resolve the LNK2019 error.

Do the same for the other `int` functions if you want to make them inline.

Comment: I originally had the functions inlined in both the declaration and definition, but it was still causing the error. However, following your example for Solution 1 fixes the issue. I still have a lot to learn about what inline really does. Thanks!

Comment: @Disaster3209 you probably should not use it anymore. It does not mean what it did in c++98. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75275572/is-the-old-meaning-of-the-inline-keyword-deprecated-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75275572/is-the-old-meaning-of-the-inline-keyword-deprecated-in-c)